# access to database from out of application

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a website on a shared server . it uses Sql server as database ( also shared ) with an account limited to execute procedures . now I wonder if anyone who has access to sql server could read and manipulate my data without having my credentials ( by using thier own ) ? if so how can I track users logged into my database and more importantly stop them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to connect to SQL using a SQL login or using windows authentication. These are your logins to the server. To then connect to the database you have to be granted rights to the database. So as long as your login is the only one that has been granted rights to the DB then you have no need to worry.

Depending on the rights you have on the DB could set up roles within the DB and allocate user(s) to the roles. This way the only way anyone can do anything in your db is if they are a member of the roles you have set up (or they have an SA account on the server or have also been set up with dbo rights on the database).

Again depending on what rights you have on the server you could set up a trace (google sp_trace_create and sp_trace_setevent) to capture logins to your database this writes to the harddrive of the server and then you can use fn_trace_gettable to query this data.

Comment: I agree with your answer wholeheartedly, but I suspect the 'depending on your rights' bits will sink the OP. If they simply have an account with Execute permissions, they won't have the capability to prevent or even detect other users' involvement.

Comment: True i was assuming it was the website that had the execute rights not the user else how would they create the tables, stored procs, views etc on the db in the first place.

Comment: so , there is now way to block sa user !?

Comment: No the sa login (and all logins with sa rights) have full control of the server. Some companies will remove the sa login from the server but there will always be at least one login on the server with sa access. This is so they can use that user to perform all configuration on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The problem goes beyond Execute permissions and logging access...

The bottom line is that you and your data are at the mercy of the the host. If they can be trusted and are competent, your data should be safe. However, if you are unsure, or **if you are storing data that is too valuable to risk**, your only choices are to either encrypt the data so that nothing useful can be gleamed from it and make sure you have a backup, or find a different host who *will* provide appropriate safeguards.